# Ace editor in chrome extension fetches files from wrong location

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ace-editor

I am writing a small browser extension which converts a textarea into an Ace editor. I'm initiating the Ace editor in SQL Mode. This requires the Ace editor to download a few external JS files.

But it tries fetching the files from the current site where the extension is running.

*manifest.json*

```
...
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://workbench.developerforce.com/query.php*"],
      "css": [
        "styles/extension.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "scripts/jquery.min.js",
        "scripts/ace.js",
        "pages/init.js"
      ]
    }
]
...
```

*init.js*

```
$("#soql_query_textarea").parent().append("<div id='editor'>SELECT id FROM Account;</div>");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/clouds");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");
```

I get 404s when it sends request like this -

```
GET https://example.com/theme-clouds.js 
GET https://example.com/mode-sql.js
```

How do I make Ace fetch files from the extension's files or from the CDN?

Comment: Try exposing theme path in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and use [ace.config.set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18347807)

Comment: @wOxxOm - Aha! This is what I was looking for. Post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using jQuery so how about using jQuery's `.getScript()` to load the script from cdn and calling `setTheme()` after loading was successful.

```
$.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/theme-clouds.js", function(){
   editor.setTheme("ace/theme/clouds");
});
```

and for `setMode()`:

```
$.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/mode-sql.js", function(){
   editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");
});
```

---

it might make sense to use the following functions for flexibility:

```
function changeAceTheme(edtr, thm) {
    $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/theme-" + thm + ".js", function() {
        edtr.setTheme("ace/theme/" + thm);
    });
}

function changeAceMode(edtr, mde) {
    $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/mode-" + mde + ".js", function() {
        edtr.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + mde);
    });
}
```

and call them like this:

```
changeAceTheme(editor, "clouds")
changeAceMode(editor, "sql")
```

Comment: This is one way of going about. Appreciate it!

Comment: But if I'm not wrong there must be another solution. Cause this solution will be a little complex if say I want to have multiple themes option.

Comment: I tried using cdn path with `setTheme()` but it seems to force relative paths. so this might me the only way since the official API says: "theme should exist, and be a directory path" I wish they'd include a flag to load from cdn but currently we have to load theme BEFORE calling the comand.

Comment: Updated answer with a suggestion on how to handle multiple themes option.

Comment: I do the same except it's not CDN, but local version. Still same issue (minified version) - requesting for `http://example.com/mode-json.js`. Does it make difference?

Answer (score 0):

add folder with ace to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) section of the manifest, and load ace from it using script element.